# How to adjust p-value for slow features?

Tags: regression, p-value

I have some monthly, weekly and daily features. I want to do regression against a daily target. I use `locf` to fill monthly/weekly features. Also I have some moving average of daily features. All these are slow in the sense that,

1) they have much less independent data

2) they have lower sd

Therefore I think they will boost the p-value/r-squared/t-statistics compared to other normal daily features. How do I adjust these statistics?

Edit:
I did not notice the source of the problem is my `y` has some auto correlation.
I have created two examples with this problem.

Normal x:

```
library(zoo)
n = 1000
list_p = list()

for (ii in 1:1000){

    y <- rnorm(n)
    y[(1:n)%%5!=1] <- NA
    y = na.locf(y)

    x <- rnorm(n)

    p = summary(lm(y~x))$coefficients[2,4]
    list_p[[ii]] = p
}

sum(unlist(list_p) < 0.05)
#56
```

x created with `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
n = 1000
list_p = list()

for (ii in 1:1000){

    y <- rnorm(n)
    y[(1:n)%%5!=1] <- NA
    y = na.locf(y)

    x_5 <- rnorm(n)
    x_5[(1:n)%%5!=1] <- NA
    x_5 = na.locf(x_5)

    p = summary(lm(y~x_5))$coefficients[2,4]
    list_p[[ii]] = p
}

sum(unlist(list_p) < 0.05)
#398
```

Comment: Why do you think they will "boost" these things and why do you want to "adjust" that?

Comment: @PeterFlom I always observe that in my data and thought it's always true, now I think the problem is all my `y` are auto-correlated. Please see my edit.